# Should I create a state for a separate page?

Tags: angular, state, ngxs

I create an application by angular and ngxs for first time. I create store for sharing data. But for some pages that don't share data for example edit a special item, should I create a special store for it, something like `item-edit.state.ts`?

I tried finding many examples of ngxs but could not anwser this question by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the size of your application you can have a global state and create separate selectors for your pages. For example, you could have `item-edit.selectors.ts` like the following:

```js
export class ItemEditingSelectors {
  // uses the global state MyState
  @Selector([MyState])
  static viewModel(state: MyStateModel) {
    // do your selection logic here
  }
}
```

I personally like to have selectors doing the heavy lifting logic of parsing my state into what the pages/components need so you can leverage their memoization.

A plus from this approach is that you decouple your page/components from the shape of your state making it easier to perform changes in your state if needed without big impacts on the consumer page/components.